# How to keep part of a char and remove anything else in R using gsub?

Tags: r

currently this is what i came up with, but i feel like there has to be some other better way， with only base R or dplyr
I want to keep the numbers between `-` and remove anything else.
Expected output would be 10 here.

```
c = "2020-10-13"

a = gsub("^.*?-","",c)

a = gsub("-\\d*","", a)
```

Comment: Your desired output should only contain `10` or month number? and whether all the other elements start with year and ends with day number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `gsub` like this

```
> gsub(".*?-(\\d+).*", "\\1", "2020-10-13")
[1] "10"
```

Comment: Thank you, would you mind explaining what the regex means after ```?-```

Comment: @JasonY `?` here gives with the shortest match. That means, it match ends with the first occurrence of `-`. If we don't use `?`, it then ends with the last `-`.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear with my question, i was asking about this ```(\\d+).*``` part. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JasonY  we use `(\\d+)` to group digitals, which will be referred as `\\1` for the replacement in the following argument.

Answer (score 2):

Using `regmatches` and `regexpr` from base R, Assuming here this is the consistent format in your data:

```
string <- "2020-10-13"
g <- gregexpr('(?<=-)\\d+(?=-)', string, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(string, g)
```

Also in case if its a date, you can try(without using regex):

```
format(as.Date(string), "%m")
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the other elements are in the same format this could help, however it may not be the best solution for different formats. It's just simple:

```
library(stringr)

c = "2020-10-13"

str_sub(c, 6, -4L)

[1] "10"
```

Just in parallel with another good answer you got, you can also extract the month
you can use `lubridate` package functions:

```
library(lubridate)

month(ymd(c))

[1] 10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract` and lookaround:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(c, "(?<=-)\\d+(?=-)")
```

Here, `(?<=-)` and `(?=-)` are the lookbehind and, respectively, the lookahead; they make sure that only those one or more digits (`\\d+`) are extracted that are preceded and followed by a `-`.